# Rails 3.2.20 - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass when destroying object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dependent-destroy

In my project I am using a one-to-many relationship between games and ticker_activites like this

**Model**

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :ticker_activities, :dependent => :destroy, :order => 'time ASC'
end

class TickerActivity < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :game
end
```

When deleting a game...

**View**

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', game, confirm: 'Are you sure?', method: :delete %></td>
```

**Controller**

```
def destroy
  @game = Game.find(params[:id])
  @game.destroy      <-------error highlights on this line
end
```

.. I am getting this error...

> undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

**Parameters**

```
{"_method"=>"delete",
 "authenticity_token"=>"684Odq56+B...",
 "id"=>"20"}
```

... and the game will not be deleted in production (Heroku).

I am using Ruby 2.2.4 and Rails 3.2.20.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

**Edit:**
My ticker_activity.rb:

```
class TickerActivity < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :game
    belongs_to :player
    belongs_to :team

    def self.convert_seconds_to_time(seconds)
        total_minutes = seconds / 1.minutes
        seconds_in_last_minute = seconds - total_minutes.minutes.seconds
        "#{sprintf '%02d', total_minutes}:#{sprintf '%02d', seconds_in_last_minute}"
    end

    # Import CSV-File
    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true) do |row|

            ticker_hash = row.to_hash 
            TickerActivity.create!(ticker_hash)

        end
    end
end
```

**Full Trace**

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:58:in `cached_counter_attribute_name'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:81:in `inverse_updates_counter_cache?'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:91:in `delete_records'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:466:in `remove_records'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:459:in `block in delete_or_destroy'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:149:in `block in transaction'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:148:in `transaction'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:459:in `delete_or_destroy'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:231:in `delete'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/collection_association.rb:157:in `delete_all'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:46:in `delete_all'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/builder/has_many.rb:42:in `block in define_destroy_dependency_method'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__4425773486301104750__destroy__2967777598099461333__callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_destroy_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:254:in `destroy'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:254:in `block in destroy'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:313:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:208:in `transaction'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:311:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:254:in `destroy'
app/controllers/games_controller.rb:77:in `destroy'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__924265301303643032__process_action__1711436731218752401__callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:207:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/searchkick-1.3.0/lib/searchkick/logging.rb:153:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/journey-1.0.4/lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:608:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/warden-1.2.6/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2936395425807340860__call__2967777598099461333__callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.20/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.20/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:82:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-cache-1.6.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:140:in `forward'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-cache-1.6.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:147:in `pass'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-cache-1.6.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:159:in `invalidate'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-cache-1.6.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:74:in `call!'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-cache-1.6.1/lib/rack/cache/context.rb:51:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-3.2.20/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run_machine'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/eventmachine-1.2.0.1/lib/eventmachine.rb:194:in `run'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:200:in `run_command'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/lib/thin/runner.rb:156:in `run!'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/thin-1.7.0/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/thin:23:in `load'
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/bin/thin:23:in `<main>'
```

**error logs**

```
2016-06-21T07:15:01.216797+00:00 app[web.1]: Started DELETE "/games/21" for 176.0.32.209 at 2016-06-21 07:15:01 +0000
2016-06-21T07:15:01.223899+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:53: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
2016-06-21T07:15:01.223919+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:57: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
2016-06-21T07:15:01.223948+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:61: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
2016-06-21T07:15:01.254045+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-21T07:15:01.254042+00:00 app[web.1]: NoMethodError (undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass):
2016-06-21T07:15:01.254045+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-21T07:15:01.254044+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/games_controller.rb:77:in `destroy'
2016-06-21T07:15:01.254004+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2016-06-21T07:15:01.224044+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.20/lib/active_record/associations/has_many_association.rb:80: warning: circular argument reference - reflection
```

Comment: you are trying to delete "ticker_activity" right? then why are you trying to find Game in controller

Comment: In your view, your link mentions ticker_activity. But you call a game in the controller

Comment: if you want delete game then pass game id from controller like ticker_activity.game

Comment: Please confirm what you want to destroy, if you have controllers for both models, and in this case, please correct your question so that we know which controller you talking about for the view... etc

Comment: Sorry. I posted the wrong line. Of cause I want to delete game. I edited my post. Sorry for my mistake.

Comment: The id '20' in parameters is the right ID for the game

Comment: @Lars do you have any callbacks defined?

Comment: @j-dexx: Do you mean in my games_controller? No.

Comment: try using `:dependent => :delete_all` on your model

Comment: @Lars no, in your models

Comment: @j-dexx: No callbacks in my model as well

Comment: @Lymuel: I changed it from destroy to delete_all. But I am getting the same error

Comment: @Lars or in `TickerActivity`?

Comment: @j-dexx: No. Not in TickerActivity

Comment: @Lars, can you paste the full code of `ticket_activity.rb`?

Comment: @Lars maybe you are missing something like this on your games model `accepts_nested_attributes_for :ticker_activities, allow_destroy: true`

Comment: @Emu: I edited my post

Comment: The Problem is that you've a circular dependency between your models. Destroy `games` will destroy `ticket_activities`. `TicketActivity` is also dependent to `player` & `team`. In `player` or `team` there is other dependent associations. Please check all those associations first. Read the notice: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to-dependent

Comment: @Lymuel: I tried this but my app crashed

Comment: @Emu: That makes sense. I will check this. Probably it is not a good idea to delete a game when there are still associations.

Comment: add `restrict_with_exception` to your `game` model. That's how you can see is there any dependency or not.

Comment: please provide full logs of the error

Comment: I added my full trace